# ms word document text translation using vba code

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm new to VBA and I want to translate word document text into another language (English to Telugu)
algorithm:
1.open the document
2.Select hole text
3.sendkeys to translate
4.copy translated text
5.paste in that document or replace in the active document
6.save and close
**Code:**

```
Public Sub text_translate()
Dim insert As String
ActiveDocument.Select
Selection.Copy
SendKeys "%rls~" 'Alt+Review+Translate+Translate Selected Text'
insert = "file:///C:/Users/puser/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/INetCache/Content.MSO/A343AB40.html"
insert.Copy
insert.Paste
ActiveDocument.save
ActiveDocument.close
End Sub
```

If any other way to translate please mention it will helpful to me thank you
I already posted in Microsoft Community
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/ms-word-vba-code-automating-language-translation/ffffeaca-c87e-4bad-b8a1-e8dd23fa5f88?tm=1583086073941
I got replay you can see but I still not able to solve

I have tried Web scraping method I don't know is it correct or crossing the rules

but still having some problem with copying the translated text

see the code:

Public Sub Translate_text()

```
Dim IE As Object 'for browser

ActiveDocument.Select       'select text from open document
Selection.Copy              'copy selected text

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")   'Create object for IE
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=te"      'opening the following Url
Set IEdoc = IE.Document ' get complete webpage as document through this we can access html tags

IEdoc.all.Source.Value = Selection   'paste selected copied text in textarea
 Dim ele As MSHTML.IHTMLElement         'for search element
Dim eles As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection 'for collection of elements
Set eles = IEdoc.getElementsByTagName("div") 'search by classname at first position
```

For Each ele In eles

If ele.innerText("class") = "tlid-copy-translation-button copybutton" Then   'checking the element in element collection
'I want to copy the translated text "problem with this"
ele.Click                       'if the element is found then click on the button by this it will copy the translated text

Else
End If
Next ele

End With
.Quit 'close the browser
ActiveDocument.SendKeys = "^v"  'paste in active document
.Save
.Close

Comment: Cross-posted (and *answered before posting here*) at: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ms-word-vba-code-automating-language-translation/ffffeaca-c87e-4bad-b8a1-e8dd23fa5f88. Also cross-posted at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/44519-ms-word-document-text-translation-using-vba.html. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: Excelguru Help Site - A message to forum cross posters

Comment: I tried Web scraping method in this

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "forum" - it's a Q&A repository. Please do not use the Answer field to add information. Instead, use the [edit] link below your question to improve the question / add what you've tried (in addition). This is allowed as long as no Answer has been posted that bases on the original content - so it would still be allowed, here. Also, be sure to give detailed information. "still having some problem with copying the translated text" does not provide accurate information - you need to describe WHAT is the problem, exactly.